# Clutter.Image Properties -- Loading an image from disk

Tags: javascript, clutter

Using Javascript, and thus remarkably terrible introspection documentation, I am attempting to create a `ClutterImage` which is supposed to replace the deprecated `ClutterTexture`.  I cannot determine the Property name to use to specify a filename/uri to load for such an image:

```
const Clutter = imports.gi.Clutter;

Clutter.init(null);

let stage = new Clutter.Stage();

stage.connect("destroy", Clutter.main_quit);
stage.title = "Test";

stage.set_background_color(new Clutter.Color({
    red  : 0,
    blue : 128,
    green : 64,
    alpha : 255
}));

let img = new Clutter.Image({
    uri : 'some-image.jpg'
});

stage.add_actor(img);
Clutter.main();
```

My error is currently: `Error: No property uri on this GObject ClutterImage` which of course means that I have an invalid name for a property I'm trying to use for the uri.  Does anyone know where I can look this up, or know what the filename/uri property is called in `ClutterImage`s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no property or function for loading texture data from file to a `Clutter.Image` instance.

you should use `GdkPixbuf` to load the image data from file, buffer, or stream, and then put it in a `Clutter.Image` with something like:

```
const Clutter = imports.gi.Clutter;     
const Cogl = imports.gi.Cogl;           
const GdkPixbuf = imports.gi.GdkPixbuf; 

const pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file('...');
const image = new Clutter.Image();

image.set_data(pixbuf.get_pixels(),
               pixbuf.get_has_alpha() ? Cogl.PixelFormat.RGBA_8888
                                      : Cogl.PixelFormat.RGB_888,
               pixbuf.get_width(),
               pixbuf.get_height(),
               pixbuf.get_rowstride());
```

which should work; if it doesn't, then it's an introspection issue, and will likely need some tweaks in `GdkPixbuf`.

Comment: I get `imports.gi.Gdk.Pixbuf is undefined`. Am I missing something? (Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: GdkPixbuf is a separate module; you want: `imports.gi.GdkPixbuf`.